# How to create desktop icons for a deb package created with CPack?

Tags: linux, deb, cpack

I am using CMake/CPack for my project.
On Windows, I use CPack with NSIS, and it's all good. But for Linux, I use the DEB generator for CPack, and I have run into a few issues. Namely, I cannot find a proper way to add an icon in the menu of Gnome/KDE/etc. I know that I can create app.desktop file, and put it in /usr/share/applications. But is there some other (recommended) way of doing it with CPack?

Comment: Holy cow, CMake has tools to aid installation??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the best approach (which isn't bad actually) is to just
create the MyApp.desktop file and add the following to CMakeLists.txt:

```
INSTALL(FILES MyApp.desktop DESTINATION share/applications)
```